# How can I find a question deleted more than 60 days ago?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I'm losing my mind.

On 2019-11-17 I posted [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamingsuggestions/comments/dxuldg/which_online_games_dont_require_servers_and_are/) to Reddit (which STILL has no responses) *after* I'd already posted the same question somewhere else* that DID attract some helpful responses.

*I'm 95% sure it was here on Arqade, but I can't find the question, and https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/181708 says that deleted questions would be totally gone after 60 days.

Is an admin here allowed to see questions of mine that have been deleted from back then?

If so, would you mind sharing its answers with me?  I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem! Mods can see your deleted posts from way back. Here's the link to the post in question:

[Which online games don't require servers and allow players using PC and Mac simultaneously?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/360280/28182)

And here's the (only) answer to the question:

[image: Answer]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I had a vague memory of!